# Switch between dotnet core SDK versions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I recently installed VS 2017 RC and then automatically my dotnet version pointed to `1.0.0-preview4-004233`. Due to that whenever I create a new project using command `dotnet new -t Console` I cannot see `project.json` though I see `.csproj` file.

When I check dotnet versions available on my machine at - `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` I see multiple versions available.

Is there any way to switch dotnet core back to an earlier version - `1.0.0-preview2-003133` from `1.0.0-preview4-004233` without uninstalling.

Comment: https://asdf-vm.com/ can switch dotnet-core versions, including the sdk

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You can do this with a `global.json` file in the root of your project:

- Verify the list of SDKs on your machine:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

You'll see a list like this.

```
2.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
[...lines omitted...]
2.1.601 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview3-010431 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

- Create a folder to be the root of your project, where you are going to run `dotnet new`.
- In that folder, run this command: `dotnet new globaljson`

The result will look something like this:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.0.100-preview3-010431"
  }
}
```

- In `version`, replace the `3.0.100-preview3-010431` with the version you prefer from the `--list-sdks` list.  For example:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.101"
  }
}
```

- Run `dotnet --version` to verify.  You should see:

```
2.2.101
```

- Run the appropriate `dotnet new` commands to create your project.

Comment: I got an issue when installing dot net core on `VS2017 CE`: 
VS would install the latest dot net core version (v2 at the time of writing this comment) when selecing the workload. I installed .net core v1.0.4 as well (a project requires it), but VS would not recognize it at all. Using this approach fixed the issue.

Comment: I have a multi-project solution. I've tried adding this global.json to both the solution folder and also to the web api project folder to force 2.1.403, but the project keeps publishing for 2.1.5 - any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Darren Can you run `dotnet --list-sdks` to verify that you actually have the 2.1.403 SDK on your system?

Comment: Is there a way to switch version of dotnet SDK for the whole system? So all solutions will use this version by default?

Comment: This answer was a lifesaver. Had troubles for days trying to build NopCommerce plugins, eventually it turns out .net core 3 broke the build behavior in subtle ways and was for some reason used by default to build a `netcoreapp2.1` application. The fix was fixing the dotnet version to 2.1 in the `global.json`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can we include global.json file after the project was created? I have added global.json to use 5.0.102 sdk version. Latest I have is 5.0.103. But still if I check Runtime of outputted DLL, I see the runtime required is 5.0.3 (which is for 5.0.103).

Comment: actually, it didn't work for me, I am still searching to switch versions globally, 
my dotnet --list-sdks are (5.0.408) and (6.0.400),
any updates @vadym-k ?? !

Comment: God bless you Set.

Answer (score 14):

Dotnet usually uses the latest SDK version, unless it finds a global.json file that tells it to do otherwise.
[The explanation by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version)

dotnet looks for the file in the working directory (not necessarily the project or solution directory), and if it can't find one it starts searching upwards from there.
[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json)

An easy way to create a global.json file would be to run `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 1.0.0-preview2-003133` in the directory of your project.
[create a global.json from the cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x#globaljson-and-the-net-core-cli)

Answer (score 10):

When we install each dotnet core SDK on OS, the each project can use SDKs version separately. Because the SDK have global installation. We can configuration each project settings by create `global.json` via this command:

```
dotnet new globaljson
```

and finally selected the correct version.

The process for selecting an SDK version is:

- `dotnet` searches for a `global.json` file iteratively reverse-navigating
  the path upward from the current working directory.
- `dotnet` uses the SDK specified in the first `global.json` found.
- `dotnet` uses the latest installed SDK if no `global.json` is found.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x#globaljson-and-the-net-core-cli

Step-by-Step:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078060/14557383

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a new project using a specific version you can go to this directory 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk' then add an underscore to newer version (all of them) of dotnet that you don't want (only the newer ones is enough) then create your project.

[image: Image of the directory which has the dotnet versions.]

Answer (score 1):

You can check in `global.json` file

Run the following command

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

You will see the results

```
2.2.110 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]    
5.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: That will list. Good. And then to switch?

Answer (score 1):

The "Set" answer is completely correct. Anyhow if you are looking for another straightforward workaround you can use the `-f|--framework` parameter and set the value to `TFM( Target framework moniker)`.

For example: `dotnet new webapi -f net6.0`

the list of TFM are as bellow : [image]

You can explore all the options on [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#examples)

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu only (ex: force version 6.0 instead of 7.0) :

```bash
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
chmod +x dotnet-install.sh
./dotnet-install.sh --channel 6.0
mv ~/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.200/ /tmp/unusedDotnetVersion # Manually remove other dotnet versions
```