# Visual Studio Team Services - Specific .NET core version

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a dotnet restore issue that was solved locally on the developer machine.

The issue we had manifested when we were on version 2.1.300, it was solved when we went to SDK version 2.1.301

This issue is now manifesting when we try to launch a build with team services. 
So I am assuming they are using 2.1.300 there.

Does anyone know if it's possible to update or choose a specific SDK version on VSTS?

Comment: You can use a `global.json` to set the SDK version. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077229/switch-between-dotnet-core-sdk-versions) for details

Comment: Thanks, marked this is as answered there. Sadly the error did not go away on VSTS, so will raise a specific question about that later.