# No executable found matching command "dotnet-tool"

Tags: .net, .net-core, f#-fake

I'm trying to install `Fake` from the [official site](https://fake.build/fake-gettingstarted.html) with the following command (provided at the site):

```
dotnet tool install fake-cli -g
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-tool"
```

My dotnet version is `2.1.201`, and I am running Windows 10 Professional, with all of the latest updates.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more? When you ran `dotnet tool install fake-cli -g` what did it output? Do you have a `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools` directory? Does it contain `fake.exe`? Can you `echo %PATH%` in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: What version of the dotnet core framework do you have installed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [`dotnet tool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install) command is only installed with the release of .NET Core SDK version 2.1.300 and later. You need to update your SDK to make this command available.

Comment: Very succinct and correct answer! I have updated to version 2.1.301, and the command runs without error now. (On a different note, I think tutorial pages should take the trouble to note relevant version numbers.)

Comment: Well, the beauty of open source is that you can help fix that? https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/release/next/help/markdown/fake-gettingstarted.md

Comment: How true! I am going to try to do just that.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [DavidG answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181148/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-tool/51181356#51181356):

To check .NET Core SDK versions installed run

```
dotnet --info
```

Even if the  required SDK version is installed you may also need to switch to the required dotnet core SDK version  by setting  sdk section in **global.json** as described in  [Switch between dotnet core SDK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077229/switch-between-dotnet-core-sdk-versions) ,
e.g.

```
{
   "sdk": { "version": "2.1.403"  }
}
```