# What is the DotNet CLI 'Tool' command?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to get the library based Identity pages scaffolded into my project, and the MS docs say use this command to start with:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

Yet when I type that command, I get back the error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-tool"
```

Is this `tool` something I need to have installed or what?

Comment: I would say, yes. Also, you might want to try searching a bit harder, I Googled your error message and immediately got this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181148/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-tool). Voting to close as a duplicate

Comment: Yes, searching for the error message and not the tool just got me stuck, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'dotnet tool' is used to install .NET Core global tools. Try to specify --global or provide a path so it knows where to be installed. Paths are done using --tool-path I believe.