# visual studio preview 16.11.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, sdk

I'm trying to load the NET 6 preview 4 into Visual Studio preview 16.11.0
and I don't see an option Use preview of the .net core SDK.
tool -->options-->Environment -->preview features

Is it possible to use both Visual Studio 16.11 in preview and then turn it on to use the .net 6 preview SDK?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch between dotnet core SDK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077229/switch-between-dotnet-core-sdk-versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this tool https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check
and following the instructions.  I also got this idea from this video where Ed did the same thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YJJcv3LeWA

Answer (score 0):

.NET CLI determines which SDK to use, not Visual Studio. And the CLI will always use the latest installed SDK to build and run.

If you want to specify a different version to use then you need to add a global.json file to your folder. This can be done on a per project/solution level or globally for all projects.

More information is available in the Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x)